# finding specific directories

Tags: grep, find, directory, search

I need to find all directories that begin with `dirD` in the directory `/dirA/dirB/dirC`. Basically, `dirD*`. So far I tried:

```
find . -type d -name "dirD*"
```

and

```
ls -lrt | grep "^d" | grep "dirD*"
```

Now I'm searching for these folders on a remote server I haven't used until now so there's a chance they might not be there. However, others who have worked on said server until now insist that they should be there so I was wondering if I'm missing something...

Comment: What's the problem? Do those commands not return anything? What directory did you run them in? Also, in future, please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: yes, they don't return anything. i'm running them in dirC. didn't know about the formatting tools, i'll use them from now on.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and include that. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, comments can be deleted with no warning. Please also include the output of `find /dirA/dirB/dirC -type d -name "dirD*"`. If that returns nothing, the directories aren't there.

Comment: `grep "dirD*"` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It matches anywhere in the string for the three characters `dir` followed by zero or more characters `D`. (It is not a shell glob.) So it could match `anotherdir` or `dirDDDDDD` or even just `dir`. Read up on _Regular Expressions_ for the detail.

Answer (score -1):

Inside any dir, run

```
ls -ld /dirA/dirB/dirC/dirD*
```

Or inside dirC, run

```
ls -ld dirD*
```